# The difference between pointing at an object and a pointer in C (how to point at another pointer)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

How do I point at an struct object from another struct object?

This is the .h file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int num;
    struct node *next;

} talstrul;
```

This is in the .c file:

```
talstrul obj1;
talstrul obj2;
```

Now I want obj1's pointer to point at obj2's pointer. So I try this:

```
obj1.next = &obj2;
```

But I get an error:

```
'=' : incompatible types - from 'talstrul' to 'node *'
```

Comment: `next` is of type `pointer to node`.  `&obj2` is of type `pointer to talstrul`. Those are different. The type system of C is actually saving you from an error for once. Be happy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're trying to point obj1's pointer at obj2, not at obj2's pointer.

If you want both obj1's pointer to point at obj2's pointer, you'll have to change next from a `node *` to a `talstrul *`, and it would probably be easier to just use

```
struct talstrul {
    int num;
    talstrul* next;
};
```

And

```
obj1.next = obj2.next;
```

or

```
obj1.next = &obj2
```

if you want obj1.next to actually point at obj2, and not just at obj2's pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The `obj2` is of type `talstrul`, but `next` is of type `struct node *`, so you need to do

```
talstrul obj1;
struct node obj2;

obj1.next = &obj2;
```

Because `talstrul` and `struct node` are differents types.

Comment: But i dont want obj2 to be of type struct node, I want obj2 to be of type talstrul?

Comment: But they are different types, it means, boths structs are different things, and depending how is struct node, if you try a type cast C can not do the conversion correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following:

```
typedef struct talstrul
{
    int num;
    struct talstrul *next;

} talstrul;

talstrul node1;
node1.next = malloc(sizeof (struct talstrul));
talstrul node2;
node1.next = &node2;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct
{
    int num;
    struct node *next; //Wrong
} talstrul;

Instead of previous Use this-
typedef struct
{
    int num;
    struct talstrul *next;
} talstrul;
talstrul obj1;
talstrul onj2;
obj1.next = malloc(sizeof(struct talstrul)) //should have the memory right ?
obj1.next = &obj2;

hope this will work.
```